# How to fix 'Some files are not writable by WordPress' error, website cannot be changed by admin

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu-18.04

I'm setting up a new website. most files are not editable by WordPress.

I am using a virtual machine on google cloud console. It's Ubuntu 18.04 LTS LAMP stack.  I have tried editing permissions of the files through both Filezilla and the ssh prompt on gcloud. like it describes [here](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-quickly-fix-the-file-and-folder-permissions-error-in-wordpress).  I think i have a different problem.

I am brand new and just learning so I'm sorry if the answer is obvious. I found that if I go in and manually set permissions for files to 775 in the SSH WordPress is able to edit some files.  But i cannot edit permissions of some files even after i am in root
`sudo su`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apart from permissions you have to change the Owner of the Files to the web server user *( most cases, especially those using apache www-data )* .

The command to do that is the below

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/wordpress/
```

the usual path of a website on a ubuntu server is **/var/www/domain.com**/ but of course that depends !

Wish you the best!

Answer (score 4):

change all files and folders permission as follow:

enter your public_html folder and execute this two  commands

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;

find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```

Comment: Not `public_html`, this should be in the Wordpress folder, yes?

Answer (score 2):

My issue was Wordpress somehow wanted to use "apache" as the user.  Changing the ownership from nginx:nginx (which is what runs my web daemon) to apache:nginx worked.

I recommend trying this on ONE file and confirming with the "site health" tool to make sure it is YOUR problem before doing a global change!

```
chown apache:nginx ./*.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error "Some files are not writable by WordPress:
wp-load.php" recently as I moved to a different host provider. The error was shown in the Site Health window from WordPress.

[image]

To fix this, all you have to do is to change the permission of the file(s). You can do this easily by using the tool called [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?show_all=1). I use this tool for all my FTP actions.

Connect to your server and right-click on the file and select File permissions.

[image]

And finally, change the permission to 0644.

[image]